# Show hex values of Powershell output of GetInvalidFileNameChars()

Tags: windows, powershell, hex, powershell-2.0

In Windows 7 with PowerShell v. 2, I'm trying to see it's list of invalid characters using `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()`.

When entered at the prompt, it lists the characters, one per line. What I would like is get their hex (or decimal) code.

Amon the things I tried:

- `ForEach ($char in [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) {"{0:x}" -f $char}` : outputs characters, not hex.
- `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | { $_.ToString("X2") }`

> Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.

- `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | Format-Hex -Raw -Encoding Ascii`

> The term 'Format-Hex' is not recognized ...

- `ForEach ($c in [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) {echo $c.ToString("X2")}`

> Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".

- etc.

I'm familiar with Bash, Perl, and even the lame `cmd.exe`, but have unfortunately no clue about PowerShell.

But I'm sure there must be a simple and easy way to list the hex values of these characters.

**Update:**
Thanks to the answers below, the command I finally used was this one, which also prints the decimal value and the character itself in addition to the hex value:

```
ForEach ($c in [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) { $i=([int]$c); "{0,3:d}  {1,2:x2}  {2,1}" -f $i,$i,$c }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from missing the foreach, GetInvalidFileNameChars() outputs char's,

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | foreach { $_.gettype() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Char                                     System.ValueType
True     True     Char                                     System.ValueType
```

and that tostring('x2') method is for integers (or byte).

```
(1).tostring('x2')
01
```

You can get the definitions by leaving out the parentheses.  The second one is the one you're trying to run.

```
(1).tostring

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string ToString()
string ToString(string format)
string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider)
string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
string IFormattable.ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)
```

So (since .tostring has a higher precedence than [int], we need the extra parentheses) (I'm in osx so there's only 2 results.)

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | foreach { ([int]$_).tostring('x2') }
00
2f
```

If you want format-hex, upgrade your powershell.

Same thing with the last one.  That method is for integers:

```
ForEach ($c in [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()) { 
  echo ([int]$c).ToString("X2") }
```

Int32.ToString method: [Int32.ToString Method (System) _ Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_ToString_System_String_)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() | ForEach-Object {'{0:X2}' -f [int]$_ }
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I would like is get their hex (or decimal) code.

Since `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()` returns `[char[]]` (an array (`[]`) of `[char]` instances), **you can directly cast that array to `[int[]]`** in order to get the **Unicode code points** of the UTF-16 code units that .NET `[char]` instances represent; by default they **render as *decimal* numbers**:

```
PS> [int[]] [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()

34
60
62
124
0
...
```

**To get *hexadecimal* numbers (as strings)**, pipe to `ForEach-Object` and format each number via a format string passed to `-f`, PowerShell's string-formatting operator; e.g., to format each code point as a `0x`-prefixed hex. number that is `0`-left-padded to 2 digits (PSv4+ syntax; in PSv3-, pipe to `ForEach-Object` instead, as in [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58041140/45375), which will be slower):

```
PS> [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars().ForEach({ '0x{0:x2}' -f [int] $_ })

0x22
0x3c
0x3e
0x7c
0x00
...
```